# Exhausting DateTime error in Salesforce Data Loader

Tags: import, salesforce, datetime-format, apex-data-loader

So I've spent a whole day trying to get this working but without success. I'm exhausted so I though to ask you guys if you have any solution.

I'm trying to upload a date-time field from a file excel.csv (with dataloader) to salesforce (customField__c -> type = datetime)

I'm getting this nasty error and I'm unable to go through it:
**Error converting value to correct data type: Failed to parse date: 27260T23:01:01+0100**

Is there a way to bypass this error? I would like to know the reason why my approach is not working please.

Answer (score 1):

you might have explored and tried the DateTime format mentioned here in this help article but if not please give it a try.

‘Date Time’ field acceptable formats
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325035&type=1

Please make sure your csv column which contains the Datetime value follow one of these format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using DataLoader or just when performing a load in Salesforce which involves DateTime fields, the format that you should use is this one:

**2021-10-20T17:48:54.638+02:00**

The part that you have before the "T" (**27260**) doesn't represent a date. If you change that to the format yyyy-MM-dd as the example that I've shared, you should be able to import the records.